# Como traduzir mensagem de erro do wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Olá, bom dia!
Estou com um problema e não estou achando a variável para conseguir solucionar, tenho um site em WP e quando tenta fazer login e nem a senha nem o email existem me retorna a mensagem de erro: **ERROR: The username or password you entered is incorrect. Lost your password?**
Tentei localizar essa frase em wp-login.php mas não achei ela la, poderiam me ajudar? 
Obs.: Tentei utilizar o loco translate mais ele não acha essa frase!

Edit do teste que estou tentando fazer as mensagem de aparecer somente na pagina de login.

functions.php

```
function erroLogin(){
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'rs_custom_login_error' );
function rs_custom_login_error(){
    return $error = "Informações não existem ou estão erradas!";
}
}
```

page.php

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'login' ) ) { ?>
<?php erroLogin(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

E tentei também dessa outra forma.

functions.php

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'login' ) ) { ?>
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'rs_custom_login_error' );
    function rs_custom_login_error(){
        return $error = "Informações não existem ou estão erradas!";
    }
}
```

Porém ainda não deu certo

Comment: Seu WordPress inteiro tá em inglês?

Answer (score 1):

Procura no seu Tema o arquivo `functions.php` depois coloca esse snippet

```
add_filter( 'login_errors', 'rs_custom_login_error' );
/*
 * @desc    Filtro da mensagem de erro do admin do WP
 */
function rs_custom_login_error(){
    return $error = "Sua mensagem de erro vai aqui";
}
```

Aqui tem outras opções de snippets que vc pode usar para customizar essa mensagem.
http://www.sutanaryan.com/2012/09/how-to-filter-or-change-wordpress-admin-error-message/

Comment: Tentei porém não funcionou continua retornando a mesma mensagem.

Comment: https://snag.gy/pI9xeZ.jpg

Comment: @Fernando editei minha resposta agora com outro script tenta ai agora

Comment: Consegui porém percebi que esta acontecendo um bug, essa mensagem de erro esta aparecendo até na pagina de cadastro, queria que ela ficasse somente para a pagina de login, tentei de algumas formas mais não deu muito certo vou passar o abaixo a forma que estou tentando

Comment: @Fernando a mesma plataforma do StackOverflow tem um sistema só para duvidas em Wordpress https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ Tenta postar sua pergunta em Inglês por lá que vc vai ter ajuda mais especializada.

Comment: Obrigado não conhecia, vou tentar la também!

Answer (score 1):

Opção direto pela área do administrador. Acesse o functions.php conforme imagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois coloque esse código e de um Update File

```
add_filter('login_errors', create_function('$no_login_error', 'return "The user name and password is incorrect."'));
```

Se ainda assim não funcionar, cole esse código no arquivo. O primeiro é para a mensagem nova, e o segundo para esconder a mensagem padrão

```
function login_error_override()
{
    return 'The user name and password is incorrect.';
}
add_filter('login_errors', 'login_error_override');

add_filter('login_errors', create_function('$a', 'return null;'));
```

Fonte de referência: https://whatswp.com/change-wordpress-login-error-message/

Comment: Ao incluir esse codigo me retorna erro  add_filter('login_errors', create_function('$no_login_error', 'return "The user name and password is incorrect."'));

Comment: Esse erro que me apresenta: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';' in /home/hostp064/public_html/49_best/wp-content/themes/Divi/functions.php(8823) : runtime-created function on line 1

Comment: Ao incluir esse outro codigo ele remove a mensagem de erro, porém remove todas as outras também.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta poderia verificar se pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver meu problema, segue o codigo para caso alguem necessite dessa solução:

```
add_filter('login_errors','login_error_message');

    function login_error_message($error){
        //check if that's the error you are looking for
        $pos = strpos($error, 'incorrect');
        if (is_int($pos)) {
            //its the right error so you can overwrite it
            $error = "Um ou mais campo estão em branco ou dados não existem!";
        }
        return $error;
    }
```

Fonte de onde localizei a resposta: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25099/change-login-error-messages